# Why is the child div clipped even if overflow-y of the parent is auto or visible

Tags: html, css, less

There is a parent div whose position is set to relative. And there is a child div that has position absolute. I want to place it on top of the parent div but it hides the content as parent's overflow-x and overflow-y are auto.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.popover-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.popover {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="popover-container">
    <div class="popover">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I set the parents overflow-x and overflow-y both to visible then it works. But if I only set the overflow-y to visible it is hidden.

I cannot set overflow-x to visible it works fine.

Is there anyway to achieve this without setting overflow-x to visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in this [beautiful blogpost](https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/):

We need to add a parent div to container and after make the popover position relative to this grand parent.

```css
.parent-container {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.popover-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.popover {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="popover-container">
      <div class="popover">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that what "works" is when overflow is not set to auto or is not declared. Does it not work to simply not declare overflow?

If you need more help than this, please include an image of the desired result.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

.popover-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.popover {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="popover-container">
    <div class="popover">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container must have scroll-x: auto as it is used by a custom scroll.